# Incorrect association in fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

I'm following the guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures with Rails 4.1.1 and using named fixtures within one another in the https://github.com/codetriage/codetriage project. However when I try to reference one fixture from another it doesn't work:

```
# fixtures/issues.rb

issue_triage_sandbox_issue:
  id: 4
  comment_count:
  url: https://api.github.com/repos/bemurphy/issue_triage_sandbox/issues/1
  last_touched_at: 2012-11-10 22:20:24.000000000 Z
  number: 1
  created_at: 2012-11-10 23:23:45.281189000 Z
  updated_at: 2012-11-10 23:23:45.281189000 Z
  repo: issue_triage_sandbox
  title: first test issue in sinatra
  html_url: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/1
  state: open
```

and

```
# fixtures/users.rb

issue_triage_sandbox:
  id: 1
  user_name: bemurphy
  name: issue_triage_sandbox
  full_name: bemurphy/issue_triage_sandbox
  language: ruby
  created_at: 2012-11-10 21:50:48.351554000 Z
  updated_at: 2012-11-10 21:50:48.351554000 Z
  issues_count: 1
```

You can see that the issue should be loading the repo `issue_triage_sandbox` repo. But in my tests it's not:

```
issue = issues(:issue_triage_sandbox_issue)
puts issue.repo
# => nil

puts issue.inspect
#<Issue id: 4, comment_count: nil, url: "https://api.github.com/repos/bemurphy/issue_triage...", repo_name: nil, user_name: nil, last_touched_at: "2012-11-10 22:20:24", number: 1, created_at: "2012-11-10 23:23:45", updated_at: "2012-11-10 23:23:45", repo_id: 915227508, title: "first test issue in sinatra", html_url: "https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/1", state: "open", pr_attached: false>
```

Any ideas why the issue is being created with a reference to a non-existant repo?

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl /trollface

Comment: can you show the model code where the relationship between repos and issues is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to be with the id attribute in the repos fixture. 
I'm using yml fixtures.  I added the issue and the repo to the existing ones in the project.

## issues.yml

```
issue_triage_sandbox:
  user_name: bemurphy
  name: issue_triage_sandbox
  full_name: bemurphy/issue_triage_sandbox
  language: ruby
  created_at: 2012-11-10 21:50:48.351554000 Z
  updated_at: 2012-11-10 21:50:48.351554000 Z
  issues_count: 1
```

## repos.yml

```
issue_triage_sandbox:
  user_name: bemurphy
  name: issue_triage_sandbox
  full_name: bemurphy/issue_triage_sandbox
  language: ruby
  created_at: 2012-11-10 21:50:48.351554000 Z
  updated_at: 2012-11-10 21:50:48.351554000 Z
  issues_count: 1
```

From the console:

rake db:fixtures:load RAILS_ENV=test
rails c test

```
irb(main):001:0> i = Issue.last
```

=> #https://api.github.com/repos/bemurphy/issue_triage...", repo_name: nil, user_name: nil, last_touched_at: "2012-11-10 22:20:24", number: 1, created_at: "2012-11-10 23:23:45", updated_at: "2012-11-10 23:23:45", repo_id: 915227508, title: "first test issue in sinatra", html_url: "https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/1", state: "open", pr_attached: false>

```
irb(main):002:0> i.repo
```

Comment: I added docs in the guide I was referencing to call out this potential issue: https://github.com/rails/docrails/commit/071373857dddeefcb7a36f8838c03c5e88dd6e20 we should really raise an error when this is happening though

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in your project [here](https://github.com/codetriage/codetriage/blob/master/app/models/issue.rb), it looks like `Issues` belong to `Repos`. I'm wondering if the fixtures are having trouble going "backwards" in that relationship.

You could try using ERB to get the ID of the proper fixture and apply it like so:

`repo_id: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:issue_triage_sandbox) %>`

Comment: The ops problem is that the label based reference is resolved to the generated id of the record, while op specified the id they want to use. Your solution with identify also returns this generated ID.